# Calculate user satisfaction with the formula $\bar{x} = \frac{\sum^n_{i=1} w_ix_i}{\sum^n_{i=1} x_i}$

Tags: linear-algebra

A user navigates a service and provides feedback choosing one of the options `Very satisfied`, `Satisfied`, `Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied`, `Dissatisfied`, `Very dissatisfied`. Each option is assigned a weight.

- `Very satisfied ~ 1`
- `Satisfied ~ 0.75`
- `Neither satisfied nor dissatisfied ~ 0.5`
- `Dissatisfied ~  0.25`
- `Very dissatisfied ~ 0`

A legacy formula is used to calculate user satisfaction which is not a weighted mean despite being called by peers. The formula is:
$\bar{x} = \frac{\sum^n_{i=1} w_ix_i}{\sum^n_{i=1} x_i}$

where $x_i$ is the number of responses for each option and $w_i$ is the weight assigned.
Does that formula have a name?
Is it the correct way to calculate user satisfaction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quantity $\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{i=1}^n w_i x_i}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$ is in fact a **weighted average** of $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ in which the weights are $\displaystyle \frac{x_j}{\sum_{i=1}^n x_i}$ for $j=1,\ldots,n.$  The quantities $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ are **not** weights in this weighted-averaging process. Normally one might call this $\overline w$ rather than $\overline x$ since it's an average of $w_1,\ldots,w_n.$

Comment: In that context it is indeed a weighted average. But to clarify the denominator is the sum of responses and not the sum of weights.

Comment: @Greconomist : The denominator is the sum of what you said were the _numbers of_ responses for the corresponding so-called "weights". But the things you called "weights" in your question are _not_ weights in this weighted averaging process. Rather the quantities $\displaystyle \frac{x_j} {\sum_{i=1}^n x_i} $ are the weights. $\qquad$

Comment: ah I see. It makes sense!!!